# How to understand where I am going wrong in euler method

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, nonlinear-system, eulers-method

I have a question from my book and it says essentially, consider the IVP $x^{\bullet}=-x$ with $x(0)=1$, what is the exact value of x(1), then using Eulers method with step size1 , estimate $x(1)$ call this $x^{*}(1)$ , then repeat for step sizes of $10^{-n}$ for $n=1,2,3,4$ then  finally plot $E=|x^{*}(1)-x(1)|$ as a function of step size and  then as $lnE$ vs $lnt$.

Now I am having some issues and ill explain,

for the first part I get that $x(1)=e^{-1}$

We have $f(x)=-x$ and $x_{0}=1$

so I have that by Euler method

$x_{1}=x_{0}+f(x_{0})t$

which would imply that for $t=1 ,x_{1}=0$

and then for the second part it would imply $x_{1}=0.9$, then $0.99$, then $0.999$ and finally $0.9999$.

But this doesn't seem to make any sense to me. Seeing as none of these are close to $e^{-1}$

So I am confused in regard to where I am making mistakes, or where everything is going wrong. For the plotting part, I am also stuck because of this. I am looking for any help and advice.

Thanks

Comment: If you do Euler's method with step size $\Delta t = 10^{-n}$, you have to iterate $10^{n}$ times to reach $t = 1$. It appears you're iterating once.

Comment: Not yet, because im not sure how I would do that without a computer systems, and I havent been introduced to any yet or for the course.

Comment: Andrew D. Hwang is right, you have to compute $x_{10^n}$. This is because $x_1$ is not an approximation of $x(1)$, it is an approximation of $x(\Delta t)$.

Comment: Pick a $n$ and discretize $[0,1]$ using the $n+1$ points $t_i = \frac{i}{n}$ for $i=0,1,2,\ldots,n$. With $x_k = x(t_k)$ Euler's method gives us $x_{k+1} = x_k + x_k'\Delta t = x_k(1-\Delta t)$ where $\Delta t = \frac{1}{n}$. You are interested in computing $x_n = x(t_n) = x(1)$ and the initial condition is $x_0 = x(0) = 1$.

Comment: Thanks guys, trying this I got 0.34868, then 0.36603, but my program cant compute the next two, is anyone able to do this on a different program and let me know?

Comment: You should be able to derive a fairly simple closed-form for $x_n$. Did you derive this already? The numbers you quote are for $n=10^{1}$ and $n=10^2$ (i.e. $\Delta t =10^{-1}$ and $\Delta t = 10^{-2}$) so it might seem so. If so then you can try to approximate the formula for large $n$ by Taylor expanding the expression you got (this will give you something like $\log x_n = - 1 - \frac{c}{n} + \mathcal{O}(n^{-2})$ or in terms of $\Delta t$: $\log x_n = -1 - c\Delta t + \mathcal{O}(\Delta t)^2$ for some constant $c$)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $h=1/m$ be the step size, Euler's methode applied to the discretization $(t_k)_{0\le k \le n}$ with $t_k=k/m$ yields the values $x_0,\ldots,x_m$ With $x_0=1$ and
$$ x_{k+1}= x_k- hx_k=(1-h)x_k,\qquad k=0,\ldots,m-1$$
This implies, by an easy induction, that
$$ x_{k}= \left(1-h\right)^k,\qquad k=0,\ldots,m$$
Now the estimate of $x(1)=e^{-1}$ given by Euler's corresponding to step size $h=1/m$ is $x^*(1)=x_m=(1-h)^m=\left(1-\frac1m\right)^m$, and the corresponding error is $$E=E(m)=\left|e^{-1}-\left(1-\frac1m\right)^m\right|= e^{-1}-\left(1-\frac1m\right)^m$$
In particular, 
$$E(m)=\frac{ e^{-1}}{2m}+\mathcal{O}\left(\frac{1}{m^2}\right)$$
Or equivalently, in terms of the step size $h$:
$$E(h)=\frac{ e^{-1}}{2}h+\mathcal{O}\left(h^2\right)$$
So the plot $(\log h,\log E)$ should be very close to the line $y=x-\log2-1$.
This is confirmed by WolframAlpha [here](http://m.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=ListPlot%5BTable%5B%7BLog%5B10%5E%28-n%29%5D%2CLog%5BExp%5B-1%5D-N%5B%281-10%5E%28-n%29%29%5E%2810%5En%29%5D%5D%7D%2C%7Bn%2C0%2C4%7D%5D%5D&x=0&y=0) and [here](http://m.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=ListPlot%20Table%5B%7B-n%20Log%5B10%5D%2C-n%20Log%5B10%5D-1-Log%5B2%5D%7D%2C%7Bn%2C0%2C4%7D%5D&x=0&y=0).